# Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute, when trying to delete child records

Tags: linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following method inside my asp.net mvc & entity frameowrk:-

```
public void DeleteRack(int id,string username)
        {
            var rack = ITSys.ITSysRacks.Include(a=>a.Technology.ITSysSwitchPorts).SingleOrDefault(a => a.ITSysRackID == id);

            foreach (var s in rack.Technology.ITSysSwitchPorts)
            {
                ITSys.ITSysSwitchPorts.Remove(s);

            }
            rack.Technology.IsDeleted = true;
            ITSys.Entry(rack.Technology).State = EntityState.Modified;


            ITSys.ITSysRacks.Remove(rack);
            InsertOrUpdateTechnologyAudit(auditinfo);
        }
```

what i am trying to do is that i want to remove all the child records by looping through them, but this is raising the following exception ater the first `foreach`:-

```
Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute
```

I try to copy the values to a list and it works fine, but i am not sure what is causing this exception ? as i want to loop through the collection and delete the records ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Exception says it all: you may not modify an enumeration type when you enumerate through it. 
So if you want to remove multiple elements, don't do it in a foreach but use RemoveRange

```
ITSys.ITSysSwitchPorts.RemoveRange(rack.Technology.ITSysSwitchPorts);
```

Comment: is RemoveRange avilalbe in EF 5 or older ? as i can not find RemoveRange method ...

Comment: It seems RemoveRange is only available in EF 6 or older. Maybe you can try this
    foreach (var s in rack.Technology.ITSysSwitchPorts)
            {
                ITSys.Entry(s).State = EntityState.Deleted;

            }
but this might not work if this violates constraints like cascading deletes

Comment: by the way, if you always want these child to be deleted upon deleting the parent, then you should use a cascading delete instead of this code (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx)

Comment: yes i am from a DB background,, but on certian screens i might need to keep these child ..